# How to use a different console configuration in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I followed the guideline on [how to expose a semantic configuration for a bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) and configured it in my `app/config.yml` (through `parameters.yml`).

My bundle also contains some console commands. Right now this command either uses the dev or prod configuration, which is fine.

But how can I make the console commands use an additional configuration file that sets some things different than in `config.yml`?

E.g.

```
#app/config.yml
imports:
  - { resource: parameters.yml }

foo:
  view_mode: %view_mode%
```

and

```
#app/parameters.yml
parameters:
  view_mode: 1
```

How can I make it e.g. use a different parameters.yml

```
#app/parameters_console.yml
parameters:
  view_mode: 2
```

when called through the console? A new environment is not what I want here.

Comment: This only works with different environments. But you can provide a parameter to your commands, which overrides the `view_mode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to create a [custom environement](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html)

You just have to create a `config_console.yml` in your `app/config` folder and override the  configuration you need.

```
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

foo:
    view_mode: 2
```

Then in your application, just run

```
php app/console --env=console
```

This will run your application with default configuration of `dev` and with `foo.view_mode = 2`
You may want to note that it will create a new cache folder named `console`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after some more research it seems, it's the only possible way, though not fully satisfying (because some of the affected commands check if they are in `dev` mode, which means I have to refactor them).

Comment: @acme Maybe you should check if you are in `debug` mode instead [`$kernel->isDebug()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.html#method_isDebug)